# greendao sessions with multiprocesses on android

Tags: android, greendao

I am working on a large project that involves many different applications communicating to the same database at the same time.

I have been changing our system over to using `greendao` to see if it would give us performance improvements over Android `ContentProvider`.

---

**The question:**

Every time that an application needs to communicate with the database, i have it getting a new `DaoSession` and then performing the action. I am never re-using any `DaoSessions`. Would it be better if each application had their own `DaoSession`?

**Keep in mind that i am concerned about concurrency between all these apps reading/writing from the database at the same time.**

1. Currently i am doing this each time an insert needs to happen:

`this.daoMaster.newSession().getMyDao().insert(myDao);`

1. Or should i be getting a reference to a `DaoSession` from somewhere
   else and doing this:

`this.daoSession().getMyDao().insert(myDao);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't recreate it, keep the DaoSession in application scope.

PS.: I'd be interested if you succeeded to improve your performance using greenDAO.

Comment: So far, we are seeing performance improvements. We are experimenting with `ORMLite`, `greenDAO`, a custom `sqlite3` implementation and `ContentProvider`. So far, everything is better than the `ContentProvider`. However, we are not done yet. I will let you know our findings. I actually have another question, will be asking it soon. Thanks