# What are the steps needed to be performed after Database Schema generation with GreenDao?

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, crud, greendao

I am very new to ORMs and presently trying to implement green Dao to manage by DB operations.
I want few good examples to work upon to understand its working but it seems I get stuck after DaoGeneration. 
After this process I am able to see my generator files inside the desired directory. Can anyone tell me what to be done next. Or please suggest me some good documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to start. It's the examples provided by greenDAO themselves.

https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/tree/master/DaoExample/src/main/java/de/greenrobot/daoexample

You can notice that except for `NoteActivity.java`, all other java files were generated by the `DaoGenerator`.

Some common practice:

- [These lines](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/DaoExample/src/main/java/de/greenrobot/daoexample/NoteActivity.java#L56-L59) can be put in your Application scope. Means you can have one session for the whole application life cycle, according to [this answer from greendao](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797018/greendao-sessions-with-multiprocesses-on-android/15807621#15807621)
- Save your [Query](http://greenrobot.org/files/greendao/javadoc/2.1/de/greenrobot/dao/query/Query.html) to reuse to gain performance.

Some Common errors:

- When deleting record from DB, make sure to [detach](http://greenrobot.org/files/greendao/javadoc/2.1/de/greenrobot/dao/AbstractDao.html#detach(T)) it from session. Otherwise the object is still in cache and next time you want to get record by ID and you thought this is already overwritten by a new object. Nope.